# Java class file format limit(s) exceeded:

Tags: java, sql, derby, in-memory-database

I am using derby in-memory db in java . And I want to run a sql. My sql string's length is 61671 byte. But I get `Java class file format limit(s) exceeded: method:e1 code_length (72447 > 65535) error`. I know the limitation about derby like code limit must be less than 65535 byte. It's ok ([class file format limit(s) exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262884/class-file-format-limits-exceeded))

But now my string' length is just 61671. Why I am getting  code_length (72447 > 65535) error ?

How can I fix it?

Thx

Comment: The problem primarily is not the string length but the code length (number of bytes in the byte code) of method e1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my string' length is just 61671. Why I am getting code_length (72447 > 65535) error ?

Because code length and string length are two different things. Your *code* is too long. Split it.

Comment: You get it at run time by the means you are already getting it at run time.

Comment: No I want to learn it like that . String mysql= .....; mysql.getcodelenght(); how can I do that?

Comment: Why do you think you need this? The exception tells you.

Comment: I will use if clause. if(mysql.codelenght()<derbylimit) {runItwithDerby(mysql);} else {doItwithSQLite(mysql);} I will use this if clause. Because I have 100 sqls. some of them dont work in derby because of code lenght problem. So if possible i will use derby else i will sqlite. I dont run all of them in sqlite because derby is faster

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your problem is that your code is too long, not any specific string. I am afraid splitting your code into smaller methods/classes is your only option. Not only that, but it's just good practice. It's good practice to break your code into as many different segments as **reasonably** possible. Often, if you end up with giant classes/methods, it's because your classes or methods have low cohesion.

[High cohesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830135/what-is-high-cohesion-and-how-to-use-it-make-it) (and therefore ultimately small classes etc) is strongly encouraged (essential reading for object oriented programmers). It will make your life, and the life of any programmers working with you, much more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to store your classfiles in a Derby databse, perhaps you should use a BLOB datatype, which does not have such a small length limit.